# Retrieve everything as lowercase when calling Spring RestTemplate.exchange

Tags: java, spring, jackson, resttemplate

Is it possible to retrieve everything as lowercase when calling spring's resttemplate.exchange?

Answer (score 0):

You will receive the response data as specified in the responseType parameter. If you specify responseType as String, you will receive a string and you can convert it to a lowercase.

Comment: is there anyway to make the conversion default for strings so I don't have to convert it manually for every string?